# Jquery tooltip not displaying properly

Tags: jquery

We have a requirement to display tooltips for few fields on html page. Here is what we have

HTML:
    
        
            
            
        
        **Currency**

JS
    $('.help').each(function() {
        $(this).tipsy();
    });

The tooltip gets displayed but coordinates are not maintained on each hover. It gets aligned vertically such that each line in tooltip contains just one character. It happens only after repeatedly hovering on the tooltip. On each hover the tooltip size is reduced horizontally and increased vertically.Attached is screen shot for the same
[image]

Could you please let us know if there is a way to resolve this

Thanks in advance

Below is code snippet

```html
<HTML>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

<head>

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tipsy/1.0.2/jquery.tipsy.css" type="text/css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colvis/1.1.0/css/dataTables.colVis.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="https://cdn.datatables.net/keytable/1.2.1/css/dataTables.keyTable.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="https://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/css/dataTables.tableTools.min.css" />

     <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
         src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
         src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
         src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
         src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colvis/1.1.0/js/dataTables.colVis.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
         src="https://cdn.datatables.net/keytable/1.2.1/js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
         src="https://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
         src="./js/treetable/jquery.treetable.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tipsy/1.0.2/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.help').each(function() {

           $(this).tipsy();

});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div align="center">
<a href="#" class="help" title="currency">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
</a>
<strong>currency:</strong>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: We will need a bit more code to see what you're doing I'm afraid

Comment: Attached code snippet in post above

Comment: I see you are using bootstrap. My recommendation is that you use the tooltip provided by bootstrap. You can use popovers if you need additional customization.

Comment: Thanks dipole!! I think tooltip works fine. Followed this jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/LhZpX/